# django open specific html tab in response

Tags: html, django

I have a django view which render a html page in response to a POST request. I want to open a specific tab in that html page when rendered.

My view:

```
def internalManifest(request):
    form = forms.TrackingID(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        tracking_id = request.POST.get('tid')
        messages.warning(request, 'Tracking Id Already Scanned')
        return render(request, 'orders/order.html')
```

I want like:

```
return render(request, 'orders/order.html#demo-lft-tab-5')
```

How to do that?

EDIT: I know i can set the tag `active` in `<div class=""...` but that will make the tab active in all the redirects. I want to set it as active for this particular method.

Comment: This has nothing to do with django but purely javascript.

Comment: When you return `render()` it is not a redirect, you are simply returning a response. Calling it a redirect makes the question confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the active tab to the template context, for example:

```
render(request, 'orders/order.html', {'active_tab':'demo-lft-tab-5'})
```

Then in your template, check the `active_tab` variable, and add the "active" css to the correct tab. For example:

```
<div class ="demo-lft-tab-5 {% if active_tab == 'demo-lft-tab-5' %} active{% endif %}">
```

Comment: Great answer, reminds me of why I love django.  If using boostrap, you'll want to write this logic for the active attribute on nav-item AND tab-pane.